# Accessing Instance Variable in C Style Method

Tags: objective-c

Can someone confirm that you cannot access instance variables defined in an Objective C @implementation block from within C style functions of the same class?  The compiler is throwing errors saying  "XXX undeclared' where XXX is the instance variable name.

Here's an example of what I am explaining:

```
   @interface FontManager : NSObject {      
                CGFontRef fontRef;
   }

   static int CstyleFunction() {
        NSUInteger emSize = CGFontGetUnitsPerEm(fontRef);
   }
```

I want to verify that I cannot use "fontRef" from withing "CstyleFunction".

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anomie and @jlehr are correct, the C function has no concept of the FontManager object and its current state, it just happens to live in the same file.

However, if FontManager is a singleton and you make fontRef a property (or create an accessor for it), then it would be possible to access the value within your C class:

```
static int CstyleMethod() {
    FontManager *fm = [FontManager sharedManager];
    NSUInteger emSize = CGFontGetUnitsPerEm(fm.fontRef);
}
```

Bottom line, you can mix-and-match C and ObjC syntax within C functions & ObjC methods. But because C functions have no default reference to self (and the object's associated instance variables), you can only reference ObjC objects that are singletons, stored in a global variable, or passed in as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had done some more research about this topic and am understanding this concept.  I have since implemented the use of a static C variable that holds a reference to an instance of my class.  I use this to call my instance property methods in order to access the instance variables from within C functions (and not methods as others have wisely corrected me on).

Answer (score 3):

A "C style method" doesn't really deserve the name "method", I'd call it a "function" instead as in C.

A C function has no `self`, so it cannot implicitly access ivars as a method can. If you pass an instance to the C function as a parameter, you can access ivars in the same manner you would access a field in a struct pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the first response.  I would consider this a great answer, but @skue's post below provides two options for resolving the issue.  Also thank you for the correction on my semantics.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. You seem to be mixing up methods and functions though. Methods exist only in Objective-C. What you're referring to as a 'C style method' is really just a C function.

C is not an object-oriented programming language. Since there's no such thing as an object in C, there's also no such thing as an instance variable in C, so the `fontRef` instance variable would not be visible in the function you posted, nor for that matter in any other C function in your program.

Comment: Good point.  I've seen this argument that C functions should not be called methods in other posts, and it is a valid one.  Semantics are important when trying to understand concepts.  I appreciate the feedback.