# Using Instance Variables in Functions

Tags: objective-c, c, instance-variables

So, this might be a really simple question and if it's obvious, I'd like to apologise now but I couldn't find answers to it anywhere. So, here it is. Supposing I have a class:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property int Radius;
@property int Iterations;
@property UInt32 * Data;

@end
```

and in my implementation file I have:

```
@interface MyClass()

void Foo(int * newData);

@end

@implementation MyClass

// Synthesize block
// Getter-Setter block

void Foo(int *newData) {
    // Do some stuff
    _Iterations++;                   // Use of undeclared identifier _Iterations
    Iterations++;                    // Use of undeclared identifier Iterations
    self.Iterations++;               // Use of undeclared identifier self
}

@end
```

Could someone explain why I'm having this error and how I should go about fixing it?

Thanks,

Comment: I assume your "Foo" is a method. If it is, then this is how you create a method in Obj-C: - (void) Foo:(int)newData { _Iterations++; }

Comment: @PepengHapon No, Foo is a C-style function

Comment: @Woody1193: That is the problem. You have defined it as a (global) C function, which is  unrelated to the class, and therefore has no access to any instance variables.

Comment: I messed up my own answer (too quick to type) and so I'll leave the door open for @MartinR or someone else to answer this one.

Comment: @Woody1193 - "C is not an object-oriented programming language. Since there's no such thing as an object in C, there's also no such thing as an instance variable in C..." From this ref, i think you can read about : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268579/accessing-instance-variable-in-c-style-method

Comment: @MartinR But I defined it inside that `@interface MyClass() . . . @end` block. Is that still global scope?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the helpful link. That has thoroughly explained the issue to me.

Comment: @Woody1193: It was  Pepeng Hapon, not me,  who provided the link and also pointed out the problem already in the first comment :)

Comment: So it was, well @PepengHapon thank you as well